# How to capture data in angularjs scope from autocomplete location text field

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, spring, rest

I'm working on one angularjs form which includes location text field. For location text field I'm using google maps to autocomplete. Problem is, I'm unable to store full data database using data-ng-model. Because, only entered text is getting binded and stored in database, not full data. For Example, If I type "Pun" autocomplete populates "Pune, Maharashtra, India",  but only "Pun" is storing in database(because I only typed "Pun" in text field. How to capture full data and convert it into json and store it in database? Please help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Here is my code:

**JavaScript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">


    var app = angular.module('formSubmit', []);




    app.controller('FormSubmitController',[ '$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {

    /*    $scope.myDataBlurred = $scope.area; */
        $scope.list = [];
            $scope.headerText = 'AngularJS Post Form Spring MVC example: Submit below form';

             $scope.blurred = function() {
                 $scope.myDataBlurred = $scope.area;
              }
            $scope.submit = function() {




                var formData = {

                        "agreement_exp_date" : $scope.agreement_exp_date,
                        "amenities" : $scope.amenities,
                        "area": $scope.myDataBlurred,
                        "bathrooms" : $scope.bathrooms,
                        "bedrooms" : $scope.bedrooms,
                        "State": $scope.State,
                        "city": $scope.city,
                        "country" : $scope.country,
                        "current_property_status" :$scope.current_property_status,
                        "car_spaces" : $scope.car_spaces,
                        "expired" : $scope.expired,
                        "furnished" : $scope.furnished,
                        "floor_or_level" : $scope.floor_or_level,
                        "house_number" : $scope.house_number,
                        "notes" : $scope.notes,
                        "ofname" : $scope.ofname,
                        "pfname" : $scope.pfname,
                        "parking_type" : $scope.parking_type,
                        "pincode" : $scope.pincode,
                        "prop_avail_date" : $scope.prop_avail_date,
                        "prpty_owner_email_id" : $scope.prpty_owner_email_id,
                        "prpty_pm_email_id" : $scope.prpty_pm_email_id,
                        "prpty_registration_no" : $scope.prpty_registration_no,
                        "prpty_type" : $scope.prpty_type,
                        "sqft" : $scope.sqft,
                        "street_name" : $scope.sqft,
                        "verified" : $scope.verified,
                        "prpty_type_sub" : $scope.prpty_type_sub,
                        "published_on": $scope.published_on,
                        "profile": $scope.profile

                    /*  "location" : $scope.location,
                        "phone" : $scope.phone   */
                };

                var response = $http.post('/Owner/addprop', formData);
                response.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    $scope.list.push(data);


                });
                response.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    alert( "Exception details: " + JSON.stringify({data: data}));
                });

                //Empty list data after process
                $scope.list = [];
                 $scope.$setPristine();

            };
        }]);
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-md-6">
                            <span> Location<i style="color: red;">*</i> 
                                    <div id="locationField">
                                        <input id="autocomplete" name="property_loc"
                                            placeholder="Search for location" onFocus="geolocate()"
                                            type="text" class="form-control"  value="${locn}"  data-ng-model="area"  ng-blur="blurred()" required></input>
                                    </div>

                        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Go for this code!

It works with the **Google Maps API**. Start by typing a city name in the input field!

Dont`t look at the warnings and errors. If you add an API key it works without!

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.directive('googleplace', function() {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, model) {
            var options = {
                types: []
            };
            scope.gPlace = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(element[0], options);

            google.maps.event.addListener(scope.gPlace, 'place_changed', function() {
                scope.$apply(function() {
                    model.$setViewValue(element.val());                
                });
            });
        }
    };
});
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.gPlace;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=false"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div>Your location is: {{chosenPlace}}</div>
    <div><input ng-model="chosenPlace" googleplace/></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering Felix.. Sorry, my question was incomplete.. I'm using angularjs form.. I want angularjs related answer..  Please see if you could help me with this.

Comment: you see in my example I set the value of the input to the google autocomplete value in this line: `model.$setViewValue(element.val()); ` - try to bring the autocomplete value in your input value, you can also use this code for angular forms add the important code!

Comment: Thanks for the reply Felix. I'm fetching value from scope.(data-ng-model's value) and setting it to database column name by converting it to json.. So hw can i set total location name.. do u have example related to that? As I'm newbie in Angularjs, I'm asking, it might be simple question..

Comment: So basically you have to add all of my provided code after you `var app` declaration minus my first line of code because there I initalize `myApp` for the snippet. then you have to go to you input and set (like in my snippet) the `googleplace` attribute. So now your're ready to go. You only have to change your current `"city": $scope.city,` with `"city": $scope.gPlace,` now until you're done.
Would be nice if you upvote my answer and accept it for the help. :)

Comment: Your code is helping Felix.. earlier there was error.. now there is no error but still null values are getting stored in database.. I'll ask you one more time, whether its possible to set autopopulated values from textfield to bind through data-ng-bind

Comment: did you do the described steps? year my code binds the autocorrect value to the $scope object field gPlace - you simply have to read it.